# How to optimize Linq-to-entity request?

Tags: c#, optimization, linq-to-entities

I have the following model:

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderUserId { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverUserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser SenderUser { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser ReceiverUser { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
public class AspNetUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUser>
{
    public AspNetUserMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(dp => dp.Id);
        this.Property(p => p.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        this.HasIndex(p => p.UserName).IsClustered(false).IsUnique();

        this.HasMany(e => e.OutcomingChatMessages)
            .WithRequired(e => e.SenderUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SenderUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasMany(e => e.IncomingChatMessages)
            .WithRequired(e => e.ReceiverUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReceiverUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

then I need to get user list with last message, where current user is sender or receiver in discussion with `username`.
I have the following request:

```
var usersDrivers = (from i in db.AspNetUsers
    where i.CompanyId == companyId
    && i.AspNetRoles.Any(p => p.Name == Domain.StaticStrings.RoleStaticStrings.ROLE_DRIVER)
        select new
        {
             UserId = i.Id,
             ......
             LastMessage = db.ChatMessages
             .Where(p =>
             (p.SenderUser.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && p.ReceiverUserId == i.Id)
             || (p.ReceiverUser.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && p.SenderUserId == i.Id))
             .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTime)
             .FirstOrDefault(),
        }).ToList();
```

but this request is being executed very long time. How to do it better?

**ADDED 18 Aug 2018:**

code executing approx 6500 ms. The code below with the same data and the same conditions:

```
        var usersDrivers = (from i in _db.AspNetUsers
                            where i.CompanyId == companyId
                            && i.AspNetRoles.Any(p => p.Name == Domain.StaticStrings.RoleStaticStrings.ROLE_DRIVER)
                            select new
                            {
                                UserId = i.Id,
                                ....
                                LastMessage = _db.ChatMessages
                                   .Where(p =>
                                   (p.SenderUser.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && p.ReceiverUserId == i.Id)
                                   || (p.ReceiverUser.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && p.SenderUserId == i.Id))
                                   .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTime)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
                            }
                 ).ToList();
```

executing 4500 ms.

As not nested requests these queries executes the same time

Why so?

Comment: How do you know it takes a very long time? Is something else faster? Is your database indexed? What does the SQL sent to the database look like?

Comment: @NetMage added some code

Comment: Have you checked with sql profiler what sql’s are being executed?